CORS Policy Issue in Spring Boot with React Frontend
I am encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when trying to access certain endpoints in my Spring Boot application from my React frontend. I have configured CORS in my Spring Boot application, but it seems to work only for endpoints that don’t require authentication.
The Issue:
I can successfully access the /login and /register endpoints, which are configured to permit all requests. However, when I try to access authenticated endpoints (like /hello), I receive the following CORS error in the browser console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/trader/hello' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

SecurityConfig clas
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                        .requestMatchers("/trader/register", "/trader/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOriginPatterns(CorsConfiguration.ALL) // Allow all origins (can be replaced with your frontend URL)
                        .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowCredentials(true) // Allow credentials (cookies, HTTP auth)
                        .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            }
        };
    }
}

My Controller code:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/trader")
public class TraderController {

    @Autowired
    TraderService traderService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Map<String, String> sayHello(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
        res.put("Message", "Hello");
        return res;
    }
}


React code for fetching the data:
export default async function fetchHello() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/trader/hello", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE`, // Use the appropriate bearer token here
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
}

fetchHello();


Key Points:

The problem is not caused by the hard-coded bearer token; I change the token every time my server responds with a new valid token, which works perfectly fine in my JavaScript file and in Postman.
The only endpoints working correctly are /login and /register, which are set to permit all requests. Any authenticated endpoints are throwing CORS errors.

